# CopyOf returning array

Tags: java, arrays

`jump` is an array that has been initialised.

`FunctionMonius3.difRandoms` method returns an array

```
jump = FunctionMonius3.difRandoms(posMonius.length, lines * col, generator);
```

or

```
jump = Arrays.copyOf(FunctionMonius3.difRandoms(posMonius.length, lines * col, generator), v.length);
```

Does the first option just creates a reference that is destroyed when the method *FunctionMonius3.difRandoms* ends or is it ok?

```
   * @param n - number of array elements
   * @param sup - max value
   * @param g - generator
  public static int[] difRandom (int n, int sup, Random g){
      int[] result = new int [n];
      int i = 0;
      while (i < result.length) {
          int random = g.nextInt(sup) + 1;
          if (!contidoEmParte(aleatorio,result,i)){
              result[i] = random;
              i++;
          }
      }
      return result;
  }
```

Comment: `FunctionMonius3#difRandoms` is not a build-in Java method. It is third party. Please provide the method.

Comment: Why would it be destroyed? jump is a reference to this array, so the garbage collector can't destroy it.

Comment: As long as `contidoEmParte` doesn't store `result` and start modifying it when you don't expect, `jump` will not be modified after being returned from `difRandom`.